# Align two div's with text in a box

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I'd like to add two different pieces of text in a box

[image: sample]

Requirements:

- Text 1: aligned top left (85% of size box)
- Text 2: aligned bottom right (15% of size box)

I'm still struggling with the alignment.

My code so far:

```css
/* Colored Content Boxes */

.box-gray,
.box-white {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: x-small;
}
body {
  background-color: #f2e6d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-gray">
  <div id="left">Hello</div>
  <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
</div>
```

Added image for additional question:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using flexbox you can do this

**Note:** Updated to answer updated question

```css
/* Colored Content Boxes */

.box-gray,
.box-white {
  width: 1000px;
  max-width: 80%;
  /* demo */
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
  /*left: 100px; */
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100px;
  /* demo */
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.circle {
  background: #ff0000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30px;
  margin:50px 10px 0 0;
  
}
#left {
  flex: 0 0 85%;
}
#right {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: x-small;
  text-align: right
}
body {
  background-color: #f2e6d9;
}
```

```html
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="box-gray">
    <div id="left">Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>
    <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: One last question. Is it possible to add a circle in front of the boxes ? I'm able to create a circle but can't place it in front of the boxes.

Comment: can you make a draw so i can understand better what you want?

Comment: Done. Added to my initial question (on the same line as the boxes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.box-gray {
    position: relative;
}
#right { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: x-small;
    }
```

Adjust the bottom and right parameters to fine-tune the position.

```css
/* Colored Content Boxes */

.box-gray,
.box-white {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: x-small;
}
body {
  background-color: #f2e6d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-gray">
  <div id="left">Hello</div>
  <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Flexbox** can do that:

```css
.box-gray {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#left {
  flex: 0 0 85%;
}
#right {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-gray">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ratione dignissimos illum ipsum odit odio molestiae ipsa quis numquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
</div>
```

**CSS Tables** also

```css
.box-gray {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
}
#right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-gray">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ratione dignissimos illum ipsum odit odio molestiae ipsa quis numquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good use for aligning items with flexbox. I borrowed some code from this article https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/  which shows how to use the flexbox model to vertically align divs.

Add the `display: flex` property to the box-gray div, then add the`align-self` property with the values of `flex-start` and `flex-end` to the left and right divs respectively. Other values like `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` can be changed depending on your specific goals.

There are lots of flexbox options/properties. I found this article from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) useful for visualizing what the different properties and values do.

```css
/* Colored Content Boxes */

.box-gray,
.box-white {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  /* ---- New lines here ---- */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box-gray {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.box-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#left {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
  /* ---- New line here ---- */
  align-self: flex-start;
}
#right {
  width: 15%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: x-small;
  /* ---- New line here ---- */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
body {
  background-color: #f2e6d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-gray">
  <div id="left">Hello - this is some content that I had to add to make the example work. I need the text to wrap a few lines to really demonstrate how tings are vertically aligning withi the wrapper div.</div>
  <div id="right">21-02-2016 11:02:03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats are leftover from the OP's code. I'll edit to remove them.